# spring boot quartz not starting in clustered mode

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

My spring boot application always starts quartz in non clustered mode.
Below is my configurations:

```
spring.quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc 
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never 
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO
            instanceName: myQuartzScheduler
          job-store:
            dataSource: quartzDataSource
            class: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
            useProperties: false 
            tablePrefix: QRTZ_  
            misfireThreshold: 60000 
            clusterCheckinInterval: 5000 
            isClustered: true 
          threadPool: 
            class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
            threadCount: 10
            threadPriority: 5
            threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
```

added dependency

`spring-boot-starter-quartz`

have quartz job and trigger in place. Application starts and the job gets fired as per the cron. but quartz always starts in non clustered mode:

```
2022-07-29 11:10:09.810  INFO 86257 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : JobStoreCMT initialized.
2022-07-29 11:10:09.810  INFO 86257 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'myQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
```

What did I miss folks? I need to start quartz in clustered mode. Any help, appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably followed [this](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-using-quartz-in-mode-cluster-e1d71e4af4b9) article on how to build the clustered job scheduler.

In your case however you have used the

```
job-store:
    class: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
```

The property however `org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true` that you later use, does not exist in common spring boot properties. It is a specific property, that is used from a specific JobStore, namely the `org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX`

[Referenced doc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.7/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html)

If you don't have any further conflicts in your properties, just changing into the following should fix the issue.

```
   job-store:
      class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have tried this. It still uses ```org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore``` and starts in non clustered mode. I have tried ```org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT```  as well. same started in non clustered mode. BTW,  ```LocalDataSourceJobStore``` is a subclass of Quartz's JobStoreCMT anyways

Comment: @EmeraldTablet why did you mention in comment some other classes, saying you have tried this answer and did not work? The answer posted is to use the `JobStoreTX` .

Comment: @EmeraldTablet you probably also need to clean the database tables of quartz for such effects to take place

Comment: I wanted to mention that I have tried replacing ```org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore``` to ```org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX``` and still got same issues. and mentioned about what else I tried(org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT).  Thank you for the lead though, I eventually found the issue. Will post an answer soon.

Comment: @EmeraldTablet you should also clean Database tables in case Spring had already schedulers and could not automatically change the configuration tables. In this case if you cleaned the table and restarted the application it would have received the  `org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX` and would be able to proceed

Answer (score -1):

The hint from @Panagiotis Bougioukos helped.

I had to change the configuration `job-store:` to `jobStore:` then the class `class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX` was honoured and Quartz started in clustered mode.

Finally

```
spring.quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc 
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never 
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO
            instanceName: myQuartzScheduler
          jobStore:
            dataSource: quartzDataSource
            .
            .
          dataSource.quartzDataSource:
            driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
            URL: jdbc:mysql://${database.host:localhost}:${database.port:3306}/${database.name:mySchema}
            user: myUser
            password: ******
            provider: hikaricp
```

and defining the `quartzDataSource` helped.

Comment: I doubt that you need this datasource just for clustered configuration to work. Simple defining of `spring:
  datasource:
    url: ` should have worked as instructed also to the article. This way spring would have provided the datasource it self

Comment: Due to some requirement, I need to use separate schema for Quartz other than the primary application data source.

Comment: I use spring-boot 3.2.3 + quartz(database H2 pgSQL dialect) - this have not helped https://github.com/abn-dev-01/abn-spring-examples/tree/develop/cron-db